# Thread Safe Pipe Termination

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc, win32-process

(Note before starting: Although my question is general, my code needs to compile with legacy Visual Studio 2008 MFC application and has to use MFC or win32 synchronization, please avoid answers using ie boost or c++ 11)

I am trying to implement a **Thread Safe Pipe** (A Queue with a single reader and a single writer), I did the following:

```
template<class T>
class CMultiThreadPipe { 

private:
    HANDLE hSemaphore, hTerminateEvent1, hTerminateEvent2;
    CRITICAL_SECTION listMutex; 
    CList<T*, T*> list;

public:
    CMultiThreadPipe() { 
        InitializeCriticalSection(&listMutex);
        hSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, LONG_MAX, NULL);
        hTerminateEvent1 = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL); 
        hTerminateEvent2 = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    }

    // pdata must be allocated with new. The dequeueing thread will delete it
    void Enqueue(T* pdata) { 
        EnterCriticalSection(&listMutex);
        list.AddHead(pdata);
        LeaveCriticalSection(&listMutex);
        ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore, 1, NULL);
    }

    // if Dequeue returns null it means the pipe was destroyed and no further queue method calls are legal
    // Dequeue caller is responsible to delete the returned instance
    T* Dequeue()
    {
        HANDLE handles[] = { hTerminateEvent1, hSemaphore };
        DWORD waitRes = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, FALSE, INFINITE);
        if (waitRes==WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            SetEvent(hTerminateEvent2);
            return NULL; // terminated
        }
        EnterCriticalSection(&listMutex);
        T* elem = list.RemoveTail(); 
        LeaveCriticalSection(&listMutex);
        return elem; // handler must delete item
    }

    void Destroy() {
        SetEvent(hTerminateEvent1);
        WaitForSingleObject(hTerminateEvent2, INFINITE);
        EnterCriticalSection(&listMutex);
        POSITION pos = list.GetHeadPosition(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < list.GetCount(); i++) delete list.GetNext(pos); 
        LeaveCriticalSection(&listMutex);
        DeleteCriticalSection(&listMutex);
        CloseHandle(hSemaphore);
    }

    ~CMultiThreadPipe() { 
        Destroy();
    }
};
```

The code is used like this:

```
class QueueData {
    public:
        QueueData(int i) : m_data(i) {};
        int m_data;
};

UINT DequeueThreadProc(LPVOID dummy);

CMultiThreadedPipe<QueueData>* pPipe = NULL;

void main() {
    pPipe = new CMultiThreadedPipe<QueueData>();
    start new thread running DequeueThreadProc

    int counter=0;
    for (int counter=0; counter<10; counter++)
    {
        pPipe->Enqueue(new QueueData(counter));
        Sleep(300);
    }
    delete pPipe;
}

UINT DequeueThreadProc(LPVOID ignore)
{
    QueueData* queueData;
    while ((queueData = pPipe->Dequeue()) != NULL) {
        delete queueData;
        Sleep(1000);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I have is with termination, in the above implementation, when the pipe is destroyed (always by the enqueing thread) it is waiting for the dequeing thread to know that it terminated before deleting the queue. It has to do that to prevent a situation where the dequeing thread tries to dequeue after the pipe is destroyed.

If the dequeing thread does not keep calling dequeue the first thread will hang in the destructor, also if the dequeing thread waits a long time between calls to dequeue the destructor of the first thread will get stuck there accordingly.

I read various posts about it none mentions safe destruction. Any help appreciated !

Comment: at first you need use [*iocp*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/createiocompletionport) for implementation - this object is special design exactly for your task and with this code became much less and efficient. at second - use reference counting for object used by several threads - with this you not need wait on delete - who released last reference - called destructor. and not need synchronization with another threads

Comment: Why so much "structure"? I would go with a much simpler implementation, no semaphore, list, or the termination events, just two critical sections, one for the readers and one for the writers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for safe destruction object, which accessed from multiple threads you need use reference counting on it. before pass object pointer to new thread - you increment reference on object. when thread no more using object, or if create thread fail, you decrement reference count. when last reference on object released - you can safe call destructor for object. and you not need here wait for any threads.

also for implement such queue - in windows exist special object - named [I/O Completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) in user space (in kernel space in know as `KQUEUE`). with this object - implementation will be more efficient and simply - you not need manage self list (`CList` in your code), synchronize access to it - all this will be done in kernel space for you ([`PostQueuedCompletionStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/postqueuedcompletionstatus) -> [`KeInsertQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-keinsertqueue), [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986(v=vs.85).aspx) -> [`KeRemoveQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-keremovequeue)). you need create only iocp, (kqueue) object.

```
class CMultiThreadPipe {

public:

    class __declspec(novtable) QueueData {
    public:

        virtual void ProcessItem() = 0;

        virtual ~QueueData()
        {
            DbgPrint("%x: %s<%p>\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), __FUNCTION__, this);
        }

        QueueData()
        {
            DbgPrint("%x: %s<%p>\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), __FUNCTION__, this);
        }
    };

private:
    HANDLE _hIOCP;
    LONG _dwRef;
    ULONG _nThreads;

    void DequeueThreadProc()
    {
        ULONG NumberOfBytesTransferred;
        QueueData* pData;
        OVERLAPPED* pOverlapped;

        while (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(_hIOCP, 
            &NumberOfBytesTransferred, 
            (ULONG_PTR*)&pData, 
            &pOverlapped, INFINITE))
        {
            if (pData)
            {
                pData->ProcessItem();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Release();
    }

    __declspec(noreturn) static DWORD CALLBACK _DequeueThreadProc(PVOID pThis)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<CMultiThreadPipe*>(pThis)->DequeueThreadProc();
        FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, 0);
    }

    ~CMultiThreadPipe()
    {
        if (_hIOCP)
        {
            CloseHandle(_hIOCP);
        }
    }

public:

    CMultiThreadPipe() : _dwRef(1), _hIOCP(0)
    {
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    ULONG Create(DWORD NumberOfDequeueThreads)
    {
        if (_hIOCP = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, NumberOfDequeueThreads))
        {
            ULONG n = 0;
            do 
            {
                HMODULE hModule;
                if (GetModuleHandleExW(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (PCWSTR)_DequeueThreadProc, &hModule))
                {
                    AddRef();

                    if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, _DequeueThreadProc, this, 0, 0))
                    {
                        CloseHandle(hThread);
                        n++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Release();
                        FreeLibrary(hModule);
                    }
                }

            } while (--NumberOfDequeueThreads);

            _nThreads = n;

            return n ? NOERROR : ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
        }

        return GetLastError();
    }

    ULONG Enqueue(QueueData* pData)
    {
        return PostQueuedCompletionStatus(_hIOCP, 0, (ULONG_PTR)pData, 0) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
    }

    void Destroy()
    {
        if (ULONG n = _nThreads)
        {
            do 
            {
                PostQueuedCompletionStatus(_hIOCP, 0, 0, 0);
            } while (--n);
        }
    }
};
```

and usage:

```
class QueueData : public CMultiThreadPipe::QueueData
{
    int m_data; 

    virtual void ProcessItem()
    {
        DbgPrint("%x: %s<%p>(%u)\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), __FUNCTION__, this, m_data);
        delete this;
    }
public:
    QueueData(int i) : m_data(i) {};
};

void testQueue()
{
    if (CMultiThreadPipe* pPipe = new CMultiThreadPipe)
    {
        if (pPipe->Create(8) == NOERROR)
        {
            int n = 64;

            do 
            {
                if (QueueData* pData = new QueueData(n))
                {
                    if (pPipe->Enqueue(pData))
                    {
                        delete pData;
                    }
                }
            } while (--n);

            pPipe->Destroy();
        }
        pPipe->Release();
    }
}
```

note with such `CMultiThreadPipe` implementations - you not need wait when working threads exit. even if your code inside dll and you unload dll - you not need wait. every thread have own reference for object and module. and release it on exit

Comment: The reference counting of `CMultiThreadPipe` isn't thread-safe. `_dwRef` needs to be guarded against concurrent access. The `Interlocked`* API calls are only half of the solution. There is no protection against a thread calling `AddRef`, while another thread has decremented its ref count, and got preemted just before executing `delete this;`.

Comment: @IInspectable - *while another thread has decremented its ref count* - you still can not understand that caller of `AddRef` have own reference counting and independed from another threads.

Comment: @IInspectable 1.) for access object we need have reference for object
2.) call any method on object, including AddRef, this is object access
3.) if we have reference to object - this garantee that it will be not deleted, until we not release it
*There is no protection against a thread calling AddRef* - protection in that code have reference to object, when he call object method
better reread - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/rules-for-managing-reference-counts

Comment: i yet not forget discuss with you for the same topic of my window class implementation, when i use artificial reference counts before call WindowProc

Comment: `CMultiThreadPipe` is not a COM object. COM rules do not apply.

Comment: @IInspectable - this is fantastic !! this is general logical rules. how com related at all here ?!? reference counting used not only in com. caller of any method on object must have own reference. caller of `Create` - must have reference for object, and this is guarantee that object not gone, even if another threads release own reference. addref called inside `Create` - so reference is exist here already. all correct - before pass object pointer (this) to another function - i increment reference count on object

Comment: I didn't say, COM were related. But you linked to [COM documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/rules-for-managing-reference-counts), thereby implying, that it were somehow related. In a COM environment, this would be safe. But you aren't in a COM environment, and your code does not benefit from the additional rules that COM imposes. As such, your code is not safe. The fact that you are using it in a way, that does not exhibit a potential bug, doesn't make your class implementation safe.

Comment: @IInspectable - i paste what found. my code is absolute safe here. rules is generic. you even can not explain, build poc - how this is code unsafe

Comment: @IInspectable - for say *your code is not safe.* - explain in detail - where, how it can fail. build poc. ask question here - for another users can tell self opinion in this question. COM or not COM this is unrelated at all. COM this is not some magic hardware. exist generic programming algoritms. and reference counting - one of it

Comment: My very first comment contains a POC. You insist, that this weren't possible, because somehow you believe, that all classes with a `Release()` and `AddRef()` member will be used like COM objects. This is not the case, and the scenario I described can happen with the code you provided. C++ provides tools to make this code robust. Your code doesn't use them.

Comment: @IInspectable - please ask question here (on this site) with your "poc" and assumption. if not afraid :)

Comment: @IInspectable *and got preemted just before executing delete this;* - delete this called when no more reference on object. no any threads already can not call release at this point, unclear what you say at all. and all this behavior (another thread got preemted) can very easy implemented  in code by insert Sleep, MessageBox, set/wait event in code - very want view your full code poc

Comment: @IInspectable - *There is no protection against a thread calling AddRef, while another thread has decremented its ref count, and got preemted just before executing delete this;* - again special for you - a thread calling `AddRef` - have own reference to object (otherwise he can not call object method). because it have own reference - `_dwRef`  - **not became 0** when another thread call `Release` (of course if it not call `Release` more time that he have references, but this is coding error). as result - delete will be not called. what is here unclear for you ?

Comment: @IInspectable - but very wait **concrete code** poc with you for *a thread calling AddRef, while another thread has decremented its ref count, and got preemted just before executing delete this;* - insert say sleep/messagebox before (or after ?) `AddRef` call. implement your "poc" for me and main for self. ask separate question here about *The Interlocked* API calls are only half of the solution. There is no protection against a thread calling AddRef* - why you afraid ?